# git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey,password,keyboard-interactive)

Tags: github

My github suddenly can't be accessed today. It was normal before, and the error is “Permission denied (publickey, password, keyboard-interactive)”, not the common “Permission denied (publickey)”.
I reconfigured ssh again and it doesn't work. Has anyone encountered this problem or know why?
Thank you all for taking the time to read my question!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

updating your `config`(cd ~/.ssh/config) file.

```
    HOST github.com
    Hostname ssh.github.com
    Port 443
    User xiaoqinvar
    IdentityFile /Users/xiaoqinvar/.ssh/id_ed25519
    PreferredAuthentications publickey
```

`Hostname` you can use other ip, my question same as your, i using this host can solve my prombole.

Comment: you saved my life, it takes me more than 5 hours. updating Hostname from github.com to ssh.github.com solved my problem.